# Subclassed UIView but not getting touches

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

So I have a UIView made with IB. And I set the class to my custom UIView class so that I could acquire touches from that view. But for some reason, the UIView on my screen isn't of my custom class. I tried casting it:

```
myView = (CustomUIView *)myView;
```

I've also tried setting it equal to a CustomUIView:

```
myView = [[CustomUIView alloc] init];
```

(This results in a Error when I add objects to the screen (I'm guessing it's because I've overwritten the IBOutlet or something.

So how can I get the touches (touches began, touches cancelled, etc.) from this view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol WAY stupid, I had another UIView programmatically added to the customUIView that filled the customUIView prevent any touches from coming through.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at adding UIGestureRecognizers to your view.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

I think that's your best bet.

Comment: But I don't need a Gesture Recognizer, I need the touches.

Comment: The GestureRecognizer gives you the touches.  UITapGestureRecognizer tells you when the view is tapped.  UIPanGestureRecognizer tells you when the view is tapped, a touch is moved, and the touch ends.  Gesture Recognizers are the updated, preferred solution from Apple (touchesBegan, Moved, and Ended still work, but are outdated).  They're also quite a bit easier to understand, which is why I suggested it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your outlet also conforms to the new `CustomUIView` class in your header:

```
#import "CustomUIView.h"

.....

IBOutlet CustomUIView *myView;
```

Comment: My outlet does conform to the CustomUIView class yet it still won't get the touches.

Comment: Does your `CustomUIView` class implement the touch methods, `-touchesBegan:`, `-touchesEnded:`, `-touchesCancelled:`. If not, there is your problem. You need to implement these methods in order to actually receive `touch` events. Show code of what your `CustomUIView` `.m` file looks like.

Comment: I do have those implemented in my customUIView.m

Comment: Make sure the property `.userInteractionEnabled` is set to `TRUE` on your class.

Comment: @ManOx: Those touches methods needed to be implemented in the UIViewController not your subclass of UIView CustomUIView.

Comment: @user523234: Doesnt 'have' to be in the view controller, perfectly fine in the subclass. Depends on the need

Comment: @skram: You are right.  Just tried to make a troubleshooting suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically,

```
CustomUIView *custom = [[CustomUIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
self.view = custom;
[custom release];
```

And Implement the UIResponder on the CustomUIView

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}
```

Comment: So I tried this, and replaced the UIView on the screen with the customUIView (I know it got replaced because the init method was called) so it works, however the touches still aren't getting through.

Comment: can u post the code where you initialized the custom view?as well as the implementation of the custom view